# Your build is invalid?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a build on Itunes Connect, but the build is invalid every time. In Test Flight he appears like continuously processing.

See the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you added the beta test flag to your build when you archive?

Comment: I don't understand the question; there is not enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Create a app on iTunes store and upload by using Xcode 7, working fine but when update push setting according iOS 10 and upload by using Xcode 8, build is showing error(your build is invalid). See the image in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901766/this-build-is-invalid-on-https-itunesconnect-apple-com)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Mac-OS(Sierra) related issue.I have Xcode-8 and Sierra, and getting "This build is Invalid" message and not able to share the build.
But when I upload the build by using Xcode-7 with "EL capita" then build processed, and I share that with other members.