# This build is invalid on https://itunesconnect.apple.com

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I face this error on iTunes Connect:

> This build is invalid.

Before upload validate success and then upload it, but still getting error after upload done.

I have uploaded more then 10 times but each of time getting "This build is invalid."
Even nothing received any kind of email notification regarding this error from Apple.

Xcode 7.2
OS X El Capitan V 10.11.2

Source configuration:

Deployment target: 7.0
POD USE: YES
Using SWIFT & OBJECTIVE C

Please see error in picture.

[image]

Comment: i think it refer to POD problem!
but i need more information about your pod configuration

Comment: pod --version
0.38.2

Comment: i just using single pod lib  pod 'VideoCore', '~>0.3.2'

Comment: please update your pod version first

Comment: Which one? But if i update pod than video core getting some of file missing.  Have any luck to upload without update pod?

Comment: update your pod using `[sudo] gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Updated pod version 0.38.2 to 0.39.0, and tried to upload but still same error! Very frustrated movement.

Comment: Finally upload success full! 
Now ready for submit to review!

Comment: Solution on http://bhaveshkumbhani.blogspot.in

Answer (score 6):

check your mailbox that you are using in developer account they probably sent to you the reason of the problem and how to solve it.

if they not then try to clean your project and reinstall your pod then try again.

Note: be sure to open the project from .xccode file

Comment: Apple didn't contact me immediately in my case. I tried contacted them and I got no reply. One week later, I retried re-submitting and I got an e-mail, finally. The reason in my case was: "Apple TV apps with the GameController framework must include the GCSupportedGameControllers key in the app’s Info.plist." -- they should add this to the smoke tests upon submission.

Comment: Reading my email from start to finished helped me after spending one day with pointlessly creating new builds and uploading them... :)

Answer (score 4):

OS VERSION : 10.12 Sierra

XCODE : 8.0

POD VERSION : 1.0.1

```
Please follow these steps : 

1) Launch Application Loader.
2) In the top menu bar, click Application Loader > Preferences.
3) Choose Advanced.
4) Under Transfer Protocol, deselect Aspera.
5) Close the Preferences window and proceed with the delivery.
```

Hope it works,

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same issue on iTunes Connect and I received an email from apple regarding to TestFlight SDK that I forgot to remove from my project bundle. It says 'TestFlight no longer requires an SDK to enable beta testing' so after removing SDK clean the code (shift+cmd+k), make archive and upload again. That't it!